# searchResultsTableView prevents from tapping

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I got a issue with my UIView which contains a UITableView with SearchBar and SearchDisplayController and a UICollectionView.
The UITableView is basically a container for the SearchBar to take advantage of the SearchDisplayController.
[image: storyboard]

Everything works so far perfectly from a search perspective but I can't tap on the search results although the searchResultsTableView is hidden.

```
    - (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
      {
        self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.hidden = YES;
      }
```

[image: search result]

It seems to me as the searchResultsTableView is indeed hidden but keeps locking the underlaying UICollectionView.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this? I don't want loose the searchDisplayController functionality.

Best regards
Ingemar